# Downgrading a plugin from Juno to Indigo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm maintaining an eclipse plugin that i wrote in eclipse juno. Due to a alot of performance issues we have with eclipse juno some of my colleques went back to indigo to have a stable environment.

Unfortunately the plugin i wrote for and with juno does not work with Indigo.

- How can i downgrad my plugin?
- Is there anything obvious i have to be aware of?
- Is there a place where i can find a log on what files when loading the plugin? the log file in .metadata doesn't give any information on whats happening.

Answer (score 2):

To support your plugin on multiple Eclipse versions, you need to configure multiple target platforms in your Eclipse and use them to verify your plugin.

Window -> Preferences -> Plug-in Development -> Target Platform

If you haven't touched this screen, you likely only have "Running Platform" entry in there. Define entries for other Eclipse platforms you want to support by pointing to the corresponding Eclipse installations. Then switch to a target platform, do a clean build, fix any issues and test by running. Do that for all targets you want to support and the result will be a plugin compatible across those versions.